# Failed to build coreutils: command execution failed（form macports returned）

Tags: macports, gnu-coreutils, php-ziparchive

I'm trying to install php-zip via macports to my macOS.

```
sudo port install php73-zip
```

then the macports returns this message:

```
The following dependencies will be installed:
 coreutils
...
...
Error: Failed to build coreutils: command execution failed
Error: See /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_sysutils_coreutils/coreutils/main.log for details.
```

then I checkd the log,bug I don't know where is the problem.

This is a part of the log.

```
:error:build Failed to build coreutils: command execution failed
:debug:build Error code: CHILDSTATUS 7693 2
:debug:build Backtrace: command execution failed
:debug:build     while executing
:debug:build "system {*}$notty {*}$nice $fullcmdstring"
:debug:build     invoked from within
:debug:build "command_exec build"
:debug:build     (procedure "portbuild::build_main" line 8)
:debug:build     invoked from within
:debug:build "$procedure $targetname"
:error:build See /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_sysutils_coreutils/coreutils/main.log for details.
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: Which version of macOS are you running (catalina, mojave..)?

Comment: catalina 10.15.1 beta

Answer (score 2):

The information you provided is not sufficient to determine the cause of the failure, since all the relevant piece of information has been stripped away.

If you face an error like this, the usual procedure is to open a bug report on https://trac.macports.org and attach the full `main.log` file; even better, first check if one already exists. By looking at https://trac.macports.org/query?0_port=coreutils it looks like it could have been the bug [#59071](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/59071), but that one was resolved in the meantime, and it's impossible to tell without having more information included.